# operator overloading opertator + cant convert from pointer to const

Tags: c++

> i have a sparse matrix that is created with two arrays and each array index have a linked list the non zero numbers are in there including the i and j indexs

**the header**

```
class MNode {
public:

    double _data;
int _indexI, _indexJ; // the place of the node in the matrix 
                      // clarification: _nextRow is a pointer to the next columns in the row  
MNode* _nextRow, *_nextCol;

MNode(double data, int i, int j);
};


private:
string _type;
MNode** _rowHead, **_colHead; 
int _rowSize, _colSize; 
int _elemNum;

void setValue(int, int, double);

void removeElement(int, int);
void insertNode(MNode*);
bool IsExist(int, int);

    void setElementByType(int i, int j, double data);

public:
// construct a 'rows X cols' matrix. 
SMatrix(int rows, int cols,string type);

// set the (i,j) element to be 'data' 
void setElement(int i, int j, double data);



// destroy this matrix. 
~SMatrix();

double getElement(int, int);

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SMatrix& mat);
SMatrix& operator = (const SMatrix& other);
SMatrix & operator+(const SMatrix & other) const;
```

};

> the cpp here is the overloading + function i get an erorr
>   **cannot convert this pointer to const SMatrix to Smatrix&**

```
    SMatrix &SMatrix::operator +(const SMatrix& other) const {
    SMatrix temp(3, 3, "any") ;

    if (other._rowSize == this->_rowSize&&other._colSize == this->_colSize&&other._type == this->_type) {
        for (int j = 0; j < other._colSize; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < other._rowSize; i++) {
                temp.setElement(i, j, (other.getElement(i, j) + this->getElement(i, j)));
            }
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

> here is the contructor

```
SMatrix::SMatrix(int rows, int cols,string matType )
{


_type = matType;
_rowSize = rows;
_colSize = cols;
_elemNum = 0;
_rowHead = new MNode*[rows];
if (!_rowHead)
{
    cout << "allocation error";
    exit(1);
}
_colHead = new MNode*[cols];
if (!_colHead)
{
    cout << "allocation error";
    exit(1);
}
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    _rowHead[i] = NULL;
}
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    _colHead[i] = NULL;
}
```

}

> iam not sure what i need to do the signature of the function is given and cant be chanbged any idea?

Comment: What, exactly, is unclear about the error message? You can only call `const` methods from other `const` methods (or on `const` instances). Your `operator+` is marked as `const`, while your `getElement`, which you call from `operator+` (and on `const` `SMatrix` instance in said operator definition) - isn't.

Comment: The error message is perfectly clear.    Additionally, the `operator+()` returns a reference to a local variable of automatic storage duration - which will cease to exist when the function returns.   If the caller uses the returned reference, the behaviour is undefined.   As a rule of thumb, `operator+()` should return by value, not by reference, since the result of addition is usually a distinct object from the two being added.

Comment: @Peter i understand thank.... what should i return instead of temp ??

Comment: Returning `temp` is fine.   But return it by value, not by reference.   In other words, remove the `&` from the return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `other` to be a reference to const:

> ```
> SMatrix & operator+(const SMatrix & other) const;
>                     ^^^^^
> ```

You call the member function `getElement` on that reference:

> ```
> temp.setElement(i, j, (other.getElement(i, j) + this->getElement(i, j)));
>                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

You've declared `getElement` to be non-const:

> ```
> double getElement(int, int);
>                            ^
> ```

You may only call const member functions on const references.

> the signature of the function is given and cant be chanbged any idea?

If the signature of `getElement` can't be changed, then you've been dealt a badly written signature. There should be no good reason why a getter couldn't be const. That said, since you're within the class, you can access all members directly without using a getter.

---

There's another bug. You've declared `operator+` to return a reference.

> ```
> SMatrix &SMatrix::operator +(const SMatrix& other) const
>         ^
> ```

But you return a local automatic variable `temp`:

> ```
> SMatrix temp(3, 3, "any") ;
> // ...
> return temp;
> ```

Automatic variables are destroyed at the end of the function. Therefore the returned reference will always be dangling and any use of it would have undefined behaviour.

> the signature of the function is given and cant be chanbged any idea?

If the signature of `operator+` can't be changed, then you've been dealt a badly written signature. The function really should return by value. There's no sensible solution that could return a reference. Using a static local would technically work, but that has some limitations on usage that aren't apparent from the interface.